# Asp.net Mvc how to changed Text Box to Check Box

Tags: asp.net

Hello everyone could you help me with this few problem that i'm facing i want to convert text box to check box which of this code should i changed

This is the Code--[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaRxm.jpg) and this is the view-- I want to changes the remember me text box [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STKia.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not add code as images, but add a code block to the question. This makes the question more searchable and is easier to handle for us.

Answer (score 0):

Use CheckBoxFor HTML helper instead of EditorFor

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.RememberMe)
```